# align scale bar with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.6

I am making several maps from a template with a PyQGIS script and I am having problems to align the scale bar on them. My code is:

```
# create scale bar
item = QgsComposerScaleBar(comp)
item.setStyle('Single Box') # Other possibilities are: 'Single Box', 'Double Box', 'Line Ticks Middle', 'Line Ticks Down', 'Line Ticks Up', 'Numeric'
item.setComposerMap(composerMap)
item.applyDefaultSize()
item.setAlignment('Right')
comp.addItem(item)
```

I've found the `QgsComposerScaleBar.setAlignment()` [QGIS API Documentation](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerScaleBar.html#a61dab704f042a51227aa2175f1480a85), but when I introduce 'Right' as a parameter I get a type error message. I am using QGIS 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

The `setAlignment()` method accepts the [enumarator](http://qgis.org/api/group__MapComposer.html#gac3892a8f50329522b15954283663eb05) `QgsComposerScaleBar::Alignment`. So you should change your code as following:

```
item.setAlignment(QgsComposerScaleBar.Right)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that was the solution to the type error, but the scale bar kept not moving. In the end I solved the issue making the item position relative to its size and to the right margin:

`item_x_position = comp.paperWidth() - 25 - 5*item.segmentMillimeters()
item.setItemPosition(item_x_position ,190, 30, 10)`